# How do I store the image using fileupload to another folder that is outside the project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I have this code which stores the image to the folder that exists in the same project.

```
 string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fuImage.FileName);
 fuImage.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/") + fileName);
```

Fine but I tried saving the file to another drive and another folder e.g.

```
G:\files\E-Tender\eTendingSystem\Web\assets\
```

but it doesn't work even I gave permissions.

Comment: What error do you get? Have you tried performing a `File.Copy`? Are you accessing the image "as it is"?

Comment: If I am not wrong, you have tried like fuImage.PostedFile.SaveAs("G://files//E-Tender//eTendingSystem//Web//assets//" + fileName);  Addtionally, Are you facing issue in local machine OR published version?